# while switching between android phone modes the video runs from the beginning

Tags: android

In my application while playing a video if i change the phone's mode the video does not continue to play but it starts from the beginning. all i understand is the activity is recreated when the mode is changed,how do i fix this i have no idea please someone help me fix this. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Follow these links:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html

http://davidwparker.com/2011/08/30/android-how-to-float-a-row-above-keyboard/

Comment: followed the same documents but still not able to do it

Answer (score 0):

Add the following thing in EditText and remove android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" from manifest file

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edtInput"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:inputType="textShortMessage|textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
    android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:maxLength="2000"/>
```

for more detail follow this link

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html

Comment: i have been trying it for hours and got no solution someone please help

Comment: use these in manifes file android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" it work  for me

Comment: using but still no use.. using the buttons in a separate layout is that matter

Comment: yeh..put it inside the scroll view